# Retrieve Database Query with jQuery Autocomplete Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

I have a script that should retrieve some rows from database and added into a html table according to the selected autocomplete string within a textbox. The function returns with success and i can see the resulting list of strings when i debug it, but i lose the track after "response($.map(data.d, function (item) " is called. The html code of the page is below:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutoComplete._Default" %>



<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtCountry.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var param = { keyword: $('#<%=txtCountry.ClientID%>').val() };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetCountryNames",
                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    GetCustomerDetails(ui.item.value);
                }
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });

    function GetCustomerDetails(country) {

        $("#tblCustomers tbody tr").remove();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{country: "' + country + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    alert("bump");
                    var rows = "<tr>"
                + "<td class='customertd'>" + ui.item.value + "</td>"
                + "</tr>";
                    $('#tblCustomers tbody').append(rows);
                }))
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }

</script>  
 <div>
   Enter Country Name: &nbsp; &nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
 <br />
 <div>
    <table id="tblCustomers" class="tblCustomers" >            
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="left" class="customerth">CustomerID</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody>

        </tbody> 
    </table>        
 </div>
</asp:Content>
```

In summary, autocomplete function works fine, i select one of the results and GetCustomerDetails(country) function is called. It calls the GetCustomers web method from code behind and it returns the string i wanted from the database (I see it with "*alert(data.d);*" after the *success: function(data) {* row). But after the "*response($.map(data.d, function (item)*" part, there should be an alert that says "bump", but nothing happens. What am i missing here?

---

**EDIT**

Console gives "Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined" error for this row.

Comment: jQuery.map accepts array or object, not string as first parameter. Now check your console for error

Comment: actually it is an array. i mislead you with saying that i can see the string. What the web method returns is the list<string> variable with .ToArray() method.

Comment: And what about error in console? What is `ui.item`?

Comment: It says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" in the console. I don't even get to the ui.item part (that may be wrong but i can fix it if i pass this error)

Comment: Never mind my last comment. I found out that i recieve "Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined" error on the row that i have trouble with.